# Eclipse - loading launch configurations from old system

Tags: eclipse, configuration, launch, recover

My system died, and IT has moved me to a new machine.  The old HD has been stuffed into the box as a secondary, and I've access to my old data and development.  I restored the files from the repository and whatever was missing from the old HD and I'm back to developing.

Trouble is, while my launch configurations are there in each project, I'm not seeing them in Eclipse.

Is there a way I can recover these, without going through the painful process of recreating all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

1. Select **File/Import** and expand **Run/Debug**.
2. Select **Launch Configuration** and hit Next.
3. Browse to old location and hit **Finish**